# Why am I getting an error when I bundle install without using "sudo"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Recently I have noticed that trying to bundle without the "sudo" command almost always results in something like:

```
Could not find gem 'faye (~> 1.0.0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
```

but using `sudo bundle install` works like a champ.

Why would my computer be doing this?

**Note**

I don't really know what extra information to provide, so feel free to request anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With "sudo" the command is executed by the root user. When executed like this, it also includes that some environment variables are set differently, because they are needed in the context of the root user.

This might be what's happening here, that since possibly the PATH variable (or some other environment variable) is different in the sudo-environment, it can actually find the gem it is looking for. While in your normal execution environment, it can not find it, since the PATH is set differently.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Following up on @topedro's answer: You're seeing this error because you did some actions as root, and some as another user.

Most people avoid this situation by installing Ruby and all gems as the same user who'll be executing them. E.g., your personal user account, or one set up for this purpose on a server named (usually) "deploy".

An easy way to get started from your current broken state is to install RVM **as a non-root user**, and go from there. You could also download the Ruby source and compile it yourself instead of using RVM.

Whatever you do, treat Ruby and the gems as simply some app owned by a non-root user, residing in that user's home directory.